# How to play a different song when the current one ends on discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would do it with a goto... but this isn't C++.

Code for playing Song:

```
    if (command === 'play'){
        var voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        voiceChannel.join().then(VoiceConnection =>
        {
            let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            const song = './Music/' + songlist[x];
             VoiceConnection.play(song)
           // Playing Random Song From Song List
         }).catch(err => console.log(err));};
```

How do I make it choose another song (randomly) after this current one ends?

Comment: Take a look at the audio player https://discordjs.guide/voice/audio-player.html#audio-player

Comment: Not familiar with discord.js, but there is a native event handler for ending media (<audio> or <video>), just in case you didn't know, which might be of some use to you?
myMediaElement.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {/*do stuff*/ });

...basically when the event fires (song has ended), change the audio source and .play() it